# On bounded solutions of a fourth-order linear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, transversality

Consider the fourth-order linear ODE
$$
\label{eq1}
v^{(4)} + \frac{-C_2 - 2\alpha \phi}{C_4}v'' + \frac{4\alpha \phi'}{C_4}v' + \frac{k_1 + 3k_3\phi^2 -2\alpha \phi''}{C_4}v  = 0.
$$
Without getting into too much details, this ODE is obtained from a linearization of a nonlinear ODE about a solution $\phi(x) = A \mbox{sech}(Bx)^2$ (where the constants $A$, $B$ depend on the parameters $C_2$, $C_4$, etc.), therefore $\phi'(x)$ is one bounded solution. **My question is, are there good ways to prove it is the only bounded solution, or, if there is another one, can we prove this second solution $w$ has $w(0) = w''(0) = 0$? Are there any methods, which allow one to answer such types of questions?**

We know that in the far field ($x \to \pm \infty$) the ODE looks like
$$
v^{(4)} - \frac{C_2}{C_4}v'' + \frac{k_1}{C_4}v  = 0,
$$
and this constant coefficient equation has four solutions $e^{\pm\lambda_1 x}$, $e^{\pm\lambda_2 x}$ where $0 < \lambda_1 < \lambda_2$, Therefore, all solutions of the original equation converge exponentially fast to $0$ or $\infty$ as $x \to \infty$. Furthermore, there are at most two solutions, which converge to zero as $x \to \infty$, so there cannot possibly be more than two bounded solutions (and we already know one). Generically, there is exactly one bounded solution, but I do not know how to prove it in this particular example.

This question comes from trying to prove transversality of certain stable and unstable manifolds in a dynamical system, and I am happy to provide details, but for the sake of brevity, I am keeping the question as self-contained as possible.

Comment: You mean to say that there is a two-dimensional subspace of solutions that converge to $0$ as $x\to\infty$. At the same time, there is a two-dimensional family of solutions that converge to $0$ as $x\to-\infty$. Generically their intersection is zero-dimensional, with the point being the zero solution. That you have one non-trivial intersection point gives a whole line. That line may may decompose into single points or vanish completely (apart from the guaranteed solution) if you go back to the non-linear equation.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I agree the intersection of the spaces of solutions which converge to zero  as $x \to \pm\infty$ are 2D, and generically they intersect at the zero solution only; however we know they intersect at least at a line (as you point out). I want to prove they cannot intersect in a 2D plane (i.e. coincide), and, if they do, that intersection is the space $\{w(0) = w''(0) = 0 \}$. If I know this is the case, I can prove certain surfaces intersect transversely (which is enough for me to prove properties of the non-linear equation).